# Wordpress Network (multisite) how to only add custom posttype to main network?

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, multisite

I've got a WP Network. In the network I have a custom post type for an agenda. I only want to let it show up in the main/primary site/network.  I've tried to `is_main_network()` in `init`. But it returns `true` on every site. (Is this approach too soon in init?)

Or in other words, how would I enqueue a new custom post type only in the primary network site?

This is my current code that does not work:

```
add_action( 'init', function () {
    if ( is_main_network() ) {

        $args = ...
        register_post_type( "agenda", $args );
    }
} );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to docs, this will return bool if your on main site: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_main_site/

```
add_action( 'init', function () {
    if ( is_main_site() ) {

        $args = ...
        register_post_type( "agenda", $args );
    }
} );
```